# Fading background image of element by class (vanilla JS)

Tags: javascript

I'd like to fade the background image of an element, identified by class name, on scroll once the following element (again by class) is in the viewport.
Using vanilla JS (not JQuery).

My code:

```
var heroScroll = document.querySelector(".hero").offsetTop;
window.onscroll = function() {
  if (window.pageYOffset > 0) {
    var opac = window.pageYOffset / heroScroll;
    document.getElementByClassName("now").style.background = "linear-gradient(rgba(255, 255, 255, " + opac + "), 
        rgba(255, 255, 255, " + opac + ")), 
        url(myImage.jpg) no-repeat";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```js
function fadeOutEffect() {
    var fadeTarget = document.getElementById("target");
    var fadeEffect = setInterval(function () {
        if (!fadeTarget.style.opacity) {
            fadeTarget.style.opacity = 1;
        }
        if (fadeTarget.style.opacity > 0) {
            fadeTarget.style.opacity -= 0.2;
        } else {
            clearInterval(fadeEffect);
        }
    }, 200);
}

document.getElementById("target").addEventListener('click', fadeOutEffect);
```

```css
#target {
    height: 100px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="target">Click to fade</div>
```

Let me know if it worked for you or if you need any help.

Comment: It doesn't suit my needs.
What I need is the fading of a section element background image on scroll, also I'd like the fading to start as soon as another section element (identified by class name, not ID name) comes into the viewport.